# When did the use of the substitute word "hashem" start being used?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, provenance

How ancient is this substitute word? I am not asking for the age of the practice of avoiding the use of the tetragrammaton with Adonai, for example, but specifically the use of this term, hashem.

Comment: Edited the post because Wikipedia says a euphemism is a generally innocuous word or expression used in place of one that may be found offensive or suggest something unpleasant. IMHO, the tetragrammaton can hardly be found offensive or suggest something unpleasant, that it needs a euphemism.

Answer (score 0):

[Devarim 28:58](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.28.58?lang=bi&aliyot=0)

> אִם לֹא תִשְׁמֹר לַעֲשׂוֹת אֶת כָּל דִּבְרֵי הַתּוֹרָה הַזֹּאת הַכְּתֻבִים בַּסֵּפֶר הַזֶּה לְיִרְאָה אֶת **הַשֵּׁם** הַנִּכְבָּד וְהַנּוֹרָא הַזֶּה אֵת יְהוָה אֱלֹהֶיךָ.‏
>
> If you fail to observe faithfully all the terms of this Teaching that are written in this book, to reverence this honored and awesome **Name**, the LORD your God.